# android proguard causes apk to crash

Tags: android, proguard

My app works fine in debug and also when I export to a signed apk if I have proguard disabled by commenting out "proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard..." in project.properties.

However, if I uncomment that line I get a bunch of warnings and proguard won't create the apk.  I can suppress the warnings by adding the following lines to proguard-project.txt

```
-dontwarn com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.**
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.activation.**
```

and the apk will get created but it will not execute in the phone.  Interestingly, if I remove these lines and use "-dontshrink" I continue to get these errors.  I would have thought that would get rid of the problem.

I found in http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html that I am probably missing some -keep lines in my configuration but it is not obvious what these would be.  Can anyone provide a clue?

> The default proguard.cfg file tries to cover general cases, but you
>   might encounter exceptions such as ClassNotFoundException, which
>   happens when ProGuard strips away an entire class that your
>   application calls.
>
> You can fix errors when ProGuard strips away your code by adding a
>   -keep line in the proguard.cfg file. For example:
>
> -keep public class

```
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DataProxy: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.NativeClipboard: can't find superclass or interface java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.Sasl
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslClient
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.SaslException
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator$1: can't find referenced class javax.security.sasl.RealmChoiceCallback
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: javax.activation.CommandInfo: can't find referenced class java.beans.Beans
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.Toolkit
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.ContextStorage: can't find referenced class java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.DTK: can't 
.
.
.
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.SystemFlavorMap
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: org.apache.harmony.awt.datatransfer.TextFlavor: can't find referenced class java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] Warning: there were 247 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
    [2013-06-19 14:19:30 - Flashum2]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Here is the list of jars in my libs folder if that helps:

```
05/31/2013  10:47 AM    <DIR>          .
05/31/2013  10:47 AM    <DIR>          ..
05/15/2012  09:22 AM            34,093 acra-3.1.2.jar
01/14/2013  09:07 AM            51,643 activation.jar
01/14/2013  09:06 AM            46,184 additionnal.jar
05/25/2013  04:14 PM           501,154 android-support-v13.jar
05/15/2012  09:22 AM           312,866 commons-lang3-3.0.1.jar
05/15/2012  09:22 AM           269,014 commons-net-3.0.1.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           170,927 google-api-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM             9,068 google-api-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           137,977 google-api-services-drive-v2-rev76-1.14.2-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           268,450 google-http-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM            10,072 google-http-client-android-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM             7,828 google-http-client-gson-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM             6,038 google-http-client-jackson-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM             6,076 google-http-client-jackson2-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM            64,952 google-oauth-client-1.14.1-beta.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           180,110 gson-2.1.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           206,797 jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM           232,131 jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
05/31/2013  10:47 AM            33,015 jsr305-1.3.9.jar
01/14/2013  09:06 AM           440,508 mail.jar
05/15/2012  09:22 AM           134,421 zip4j_1.2.5.jar
```

Comment: After working on this for a couple of days I am afraid that the solution is to disable Proguard.  I don't understand why "-dontshrink" does not work.  This should leave everything in and only obfuscate.  I am now trying to work with Android Studio but even it has its problems.

Comment: Hi,
Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late, but searching for a solution to a similar problem, I learned that you have to tell **proguard** to keep some classes in your libs jars. Refer to the log where it says `Warning: ...` and `can't find referenced class ...`.

So in your case should be:

```
-keep class javax.security.** { *; }
-keep class java.beans.** { *; }
-keep class java.awt.** { *; }
```

and

```
-libraryjars libs/XYZ.jar
```

for every jar into `/libs` containing those classes.